# No cluster in EMR Studio "Cluster Template" drop down

Tags: amazon-emr

I am working on setting up AWS EMR Studio so my team can use Jupyter with out having to manage the clusters on the back end.

Currently I am able to connect to a cluster that I provision via Service Catalog but I want to let my users do the provisioning from inside their notebooks. The docs show this as supported & there is a GUI for it but I can't figure out what I need to do to populate the "Select a Cluster template" drop down.
[image]

Comment: Did you ever get this going? I'm in the same position. I have created all the correct roles\policies. I have created a portfolio\product. In service catalog I have assigned the admin user role. Still no dice? I have no drop down items.

Comment: For me it was the roles - I did not have it set up so the EMR Studio user has rights to see the stuff in the Service Catalog

Comment: Cheers - Yeah I got it going as well, was missing the tags for the VPC.. Hell of a setup to just get EMR running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the EMR Studio User Role as one of the principals who have access to the portfolio of cluster templates. This is how Service Catalog access control works, where you need to assign IAM principal(here EMR Studio User Role) to the portfolio.

From EMR Studio documentation,

> Grant your user role for EMR Studio access to your portfolio.
>
> Select your portfolio from the Portfolios page in the AWS Service
> Catalog management console.
>
> Expand the Groups, roles, and users tab and choose Add groups, roles,
> users.
>
> Search for your EMR Studio user role in the Roles tab, select your
> role, and choose Add access.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-studio-cluster-templates.html

Answer (score 0):

To populate cluster templates in the GUI, you need to set up cluster templates and host them in a Service Catalog portfolio. The EMR Studio docs have instructions for setting up cluster templates [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-studio-cluster-templates.html).

There are also some example cluster templates in the [emr-studio-samples](https://github.com/aws-samples/emr-studio-samples/tree/main/cluster_templates) GitHub repo.

Comment: I've done this, at least I think I have - I can provision the cluster from Service Catalog & then attach it but I cannot spin it up inside the notebook